# Match the following with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I need to match the following string with regular expressions in Java:

> Hello: ${firstName} ${lastName}

And get this:

**${firstName}**

**${lastName}**

I tried this:

```
@Test
    public void testRegexMatch() {
        String regex = Pattern.quote("${") + ".+" + Pattern.quote("}");
        String str = "Hello: ${firstName} ${lastName}";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(str.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }
    }
```

But I got the following output:

> ${firstName} ${lastName}

Comment: The $ is reserved in Regex, try to escape it.

Comment: I'm escaping it with Pattern.quote().

Comment: @WagnerVaz - I believe Pattern.quote() gives a literal string which would escape the $.

Comment: @AlfredoO - You need a non-greedy specifier (?) for the "one or more of anything pattern". Otherwise regex defaults to greedy and only returns the longest match. See hsz's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `.+` with `[^\}]+`. which will match as many non-`}` characters as it can.

It is also important to note that this method is superior to using the non-greedy quantifier `.+?` because this will match without any backtracking, while the non-greedy version will backtrack once per character within the brackets.  In this case, you will probably not notice a performance hit, but it is important to be in the habit of writing the most efficient regular expressions possible

Comment: Could you please give further detail why the use of [] and the ^\

Comment: sure. `[]` marks a character class, or "any character in here", putting the `^` at the beginning negates the class, meaning "match any character _except_ these", and the `\}` is the (escaped) character we don't want to match, so "any character except the `}`"

Comment: It is superior in certain ways, with at least one exception (that probably does not apply in this case). It is not possible to allow escaped `}` characters in the data (like `\}`) using this method; since it seems the contents will be a name, there's probably no issue. Just a note of caution...

Comment: the expression could be modified to allow it.  The non-greedy version would also not behave correctly in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The following would match ${anything}

```
(\$\{[^\}]+\})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
public void testRegexMatch() {
    String regex = Pattern.quote("${") + "(.+?)" + Pattern.quote("}");
    String str = "Hello: ${firstName} ${lastName}";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: that won't output what OP is asking for. Also, the ungreedy match will cause a lot of unnecessary backtracking

Comment: This should work. Although you might want to let him know why you used the non-greedy specifier.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a greedy quantifier and matches as much input as it can, so your regex goes on to match till the `}` of `${lastName}`. So, you need to use the reluctant quatifier here which is `?` and it should work fine. You just need to change your first line of code like this

`String regex = Pattern.quote("${") + ".+?" + Pattern.quote("}");`

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "Hello: ${firstName} ${lastName}";    
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\Q${\\E[a-zA-Z]*\\Q}\\E");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

replace

```
[a-zA-Z]*
```

with whatever you want